# Array List of Points with GPS Location

Tags: android, arrays, gps, location, distance

I am currently working on a coding project that requires the following:

- Map the user's location (GPS) enabled with a button
- Hard code a list of GPS points onto a map
- Calculate the distance from the user's location to the hard coded GPS points on the map

Currently, I have code concerning the user's location (GPS) with a button:

GPSTracker.java

```
package com.example.gpstracking;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }       
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

My biggest concern is figuring out how to hardcode the gps points into the application. I have found similar code in the following post. As for find the distance, I think using the Location.distanceBetween() will be sufficient. Your help is much appreciated.

- [How to write GPS coordinates to EXIF data on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350037/how-to-write-gps-coordinates-to-exif-data-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this one.

package com.example.tracker;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {
    private GoogleMap map;
    private static final LatLng ROMA = new LatLng(42.093230818037,
            11.7971813678741);
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean enabledGPS = service
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        boolean enabledWiFi = service
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        // Check if enabled and if not send user to the GSP settings
        // Better solution would be to display a dialog and suggesting to
        // go to the settings
        if (!enabledGPS) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "GPS signal not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
        // default
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        // Initialize the location fields
        if (location != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Selected Provider " + provider,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            onLocationChanged(location);
        } else {

            // do something
        }

    }

    /* Request updates at startup */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
    }

    /* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Location " + lat + "," + lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Location " + coordinate.latitude + "," + coordinate.longitude,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Marker startPerc = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(coordinate)
                .title("Start")
                .snippet("Inizio del percorso")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into [markers](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html)? They're not exactly what you're looking for, but from reading your problem description, it seems like they'll fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, Clement I will look into using Markers, but it seems like @Sethu gave me something to work with.

Comment: I am not to familiar with Markers. Is there a way to map multiple markers to form a line? The end goal is to have many Markers to represent an underground pipeline. The app is then suppose to detect these markers and determine the distance between the user and the pipeline. Your help is much appreciated @ClementHoang.

Comment: Yup, what you are looking for are [polylines](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline.html).

Example: Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
     .add(Marker1.getPosition(), Marker2.getPosition())
     .width(5)
     .color(Color.RED));